# OrientDB: alias not working?

Tags: orientdb

'morning!

I'm noticing a weird behaviour of aliases in queries: I executed this query (notice the use of alias in the WHERE clause)

```
SELECT traversedElement(1).start AS stime, traversedElement(2) AS destination 
FROM (TRAVERSE both('Involves') FROM #11:11052 WHILE $depth <= 2)
WHERE @rid = #11:8395 
AND stime = DATE('31.10.2014 11:00:00')
```

and I obtained an empty result, while avoiding the use of the `stime` alias in the WHERE clause causes the query to produce the right result.

```
SELECT traversedElement(1).start AS stime, traversedElement(2) AS destination 
FROM (TRAVERSE both('Involves') FROM #11:11052 WHILE $depth <= 2)
WHERE @rid = #11:8395 
AND traversedElement(1).start = DATE('31.10.2014 11:00:00')
```

Does anybody know what's going on? Are aliases not processed in WHERE clauses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Alberto
If you use an alias you can't use it immediately in where clause.
You have two different ways to execute your query

1)

```
 select from (SELECT traversedElement(1).start AS stime, traversedElement(2) AS destination 
    FROM (TRAVERSE both('Involves') FROM #11:11052 WHILE $depth <= 2)
    WHERE @rid = #11:8395) where stime = DATE('31.10.2014 11:00:00')
```

2)

```
select start as stime,destination from (SELECT traversedElement(1).start, traversedElement(2) AS destination 
FROM (TRAVERSE both('Involves') FROM #11:11052 WHILE $depth <= 2)
WHERE @rid = #11:8395 AND traversedElement(1).start = DATE('31.10.2014 11:00:00'))
```

Comment: i see, this is a bit weird, anyway. Thanks for the answer

Comment: Just for the sake of curiosity: is it possible to use aliases in GROUP BY clauses?

Comment: GROUP BY or WHERE clause should have the same behavior with alias